How can I use the values in my sympy summation in my piecewise properly?
I have a sympy summation in python and I want to add the summation value that my sympy symbol is currently to a variable in python so it can use numbers to run non symbolic functions.
The code I'm using is:
from sympy import symbols, summation, Piecewise, Eq

# Define the symbols
n = symbols('n', integer=True, nonnegative=True)
x = symbols('x')  # Example formula variable

# Define your formula (e.g., x = 2 * n)
def formula(count,symbol):
    first = count.to_bytes(32,byteorder='big')
    second = first.from_bytes(32, byteorder="big")
    third = second **2
    return third
# Define the number you're looking for (e.g., find first occurrence of 6)
target = 1

# Define a Piecewise condition to detect the first occurrence
piecewise_logic = Piecewise(
    (formula(0 + target ,n),Eq(n, target)),  # If the formula equals the target, use it
    (0, True)                        # Else, return 0
)

# Perform the summation (simulate finding the first occurrence)
result = summation(piecewise_logic, (n, 0, 10))  # Summing over range 0 to 10

print(result)

As you can see in my code the sympy summation is from 0 to 10.
In my piecewise, target is just a placeholder, it should be whatever value the symbol is in the summation 0 through 10.
Then it should add to 0 each time n changes its summation value.
I'm not looking for any loops I want everything instant like this code.
So basically my question is how can I use each value of the summation at every step of n and add that to 0 in my piecewise?

What's your question?

@jared I added it to the end

What is the purpose of the 2nd arg in formula? symbol is not used in the function.

@smichr I wanted to use it later

You are hiding your loops in the summation code. The way to avoid that would be to put symbolic values in the Piecewise, use it to generate an expressions, and then later just substitute in the known values.
First I put in concrete values to show that the summation of a Piecewise will select out the right values
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x, y, z')
(x, y, z)

>>> p=Piecewise((1,Eq(x,2)),(2,Eq(x,3)),(0,True))
>>> summation(p,(x,0,4))
3

So we got a 1 when x was 2 and a 2 when x was 3 to give a total of 3. The loop over x was handled transparently by summation. Now I will use y and z instead of 1 and 2.
>>> p=Piecewise((y,Eq(x,2)),(z,Eq(x,3)),(0,True))
>>> summation(p,(x,0,4))
y + z
>>> _.xreplace({y:1,z:2})
3

With that final expression you can substitute in given values later without loops (kind of) -- the substitution routine will still loop over the variables.
